# Redis/hazelcast - parallel consuming without locks

Tags: redis, hazelcast, in-memory-database

The question is asked for Redis, but can also be asked for hazelcast.

Is there a way for multiple instances to work on a Redis data-structure without locks?

Example:

Assume you have a queue stored on Redis.

When an applications gets an API request, it takes elements from that queue, does some processing and then returns the elements as the API response.

Is there a way to it in a way that satisfies the following requirements:

1. Elements are not lost. Meaning that in case where elements were taken from the queue and the application restarts, before done processing them, the elements will return to the queue.
2. Elements are read by a single consumer. Meaning, if a message is currently processed by a consumer then no other consumer will pick it up.

Seems that working with transactions satisfies 1 but fails 2, dequeuing messages satisfies 2 but fails 1.

Is there a way to satisfy both?

Answer (score 0):

For Hazelcast, try [TransactionalQueue](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/transaction/TransactionalQueue.html#take--)

If you do [IQueue.take()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/collection/IQueue.html#take--) or [TransactionalQueue.take()](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.1/javadoc/com/hazelcast/transaction/TransactionalQueue.html#take--) then only one consumer receives the message.

For the transactional queue, the item taken is at the front of the queue if the transaction goes to rollback.

Note here transaction isolation impacts on sequentiality semantics.
A queue may contain "*A*", "*B*" and "*C*".
A transaction take would get a hold on "*A*", as you'd expect.
While the transaction is running the next take gets "*B*".
If the transaction aborts, the next take gets "*A*".